# Model rendering inside view: toJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, model

I have added a model attribut inside a view like so:

```
 app.ActorView = Backbone.View.extend({

        modelImg:'', ....
```

I'm skipping to the rendering part as everything else is ok:

```
 render: function () {this.$el.html(this.template({
                modImg: this.modelImg.toJSON(),
                mod: this.model.toJSON(),
                movies: this.collection.toJSON()}
```

Every model in the view (model, collection and modelimg) is correctly fetched in the rooter part of my project:

```
 modActor.fetch().done(function () {
                modActorMovies.fetch().done(function () {
                    modImgActor.fetch().done(function () {
                        var actorView = new app.ActorView({

                        modelImg: modImgActor,<--problematic model
                            model: modActor,
                            collection: modActorMovies
                        });
```

My modImgActor definition is the following:

```
    app.ActorImg= Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: "http://umovie.herokuapp.com/unsecure/actors/272994458/movies",

        parse: function (response) {
            return response.results[0];
        }
    });
```

The problem is when I use the toJson() function on the modelImg. There is the following error: this.modelImg.toJSON is not a function

Can it be how the model is defined with its url?

Comment: You added a modelImg Attribute to your view but I don't see an assignment of the model (modImgActor) to that attribute. A string has not method toJSON(). Only some options like model will be assigned automaticly by the constructor). You can add the model instead of the string when you extend the view.

Comment: If `toJSON` is not a function, then `this.modelImg` is not a model, because [all backbone models have `toJSON` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON).

Answer (score 0):

`modImg` is not a standard option for `Backbone.View`. So backbone will just ignore it.

You have to manually handle the custom properties that you pass along with the options.

So you're view definition should be

```
app.ActorView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
      this.modelImg = options.modelImg;
   }
}):
```